# SQLite: How to swap two rows only lefting the ID column

Tags: sql, sqlite, swap

I have two integers, which are some IDs of two existing rows in the table.
What I want to do is exchanging two rows' values only except their IDs.

For example, if I have given IDs 5 and 13,
I want to change

```
ID    columnA    columnB    columnC
 5        343      "ABC"       null
13         90      "DEF"       "ZY"
```

into

```
ID    columnA    columnB    columnC
 5         90      "DEF"       "ZY"
13        343      "ABC"       null
```

How can I do this?
The ID column is not AUTO-INCREMENT, so I cannot insert temporary rows having arbitrary IDs recklessly.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do this using standard SQL as:

```
update t
    set id = (case when id = 5 then 13 else 5 end)
    where id in (5, 13);
```

If the `id` column has a unique constraint, then you could possibly get a violation of the unique constraint.  If that occurs, one method is a two-step approach.  Assuming `id` is always positive:

```
update t
    set id = (case when id = 5 then -13 else -5 end)
    where id in (5, 13);

update t
    set id = - id
    where id < 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Gordon's answer works if there's no unique constraint or if negative values are permitted (which may not be the case).  If there is a constraint enforcing only positive, unique values, then neither solution will work, especially if many such updates may be able to take place at once.  In this case, I'd recommend a transaction (for consistency) in which you use a temporary table to store the row being swapped:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp AS SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 5;
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 5;
UPDATE my_table SET id = 5 WHERE id = 13;
UPDATE my_temp SET id = 13 WHERE id = 5;
INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM my_temp;
DROP TABLE my_temp;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: When sqllite works according to SQL Standard swapping those values should work without uniqueness violation. Similar to `SET a = b, b = a`

Comment: This syntax is not valid in SQLite.

Comment: I don't think a downvote was necessary here.  dnoeth, as both I and Gordon had mentioned in our answers, his first solution does indeed cause uniqueness violations in sqlite.  His second solution doesn't, but it is neither transactionally safe nor can it be used (as he admits) if negative values are not allowed on the `id` column.  That is what my answer sought to fix.  CL, you are right in the syntax in my original answer isn't implemented in sqlite - I missed it since I usually work in postgres.  I have updated it to use the syntax sqlite expects.